# Check if the x element is in complete view or not in the web page

Tags: javascript

I been trying to create a script that lets the user know if the #x element is in complete view or not so I have an if else conditional statement, which determines that.

**The if condition is triggered in this situation**

- If the #x element can be seen completely in the web page.

**The else condition is triggered in the following situations.**

*The #x element can not be seen at all or portions of the #x element can be seen.*

- Situation 1:

The window is small enough that the #x element is not seen any more or
the #x element is in incomplete view.

- Situation 2:

CSS positioning is used to have the #x element not see able or incompletely in view in the web page.

- Situation 3:

The #x element is so big for the web page to see completely that a portion of it is shown regardless if there is a scroll bar or not.
So even if the #x element is a pixel off in view then the else condition is still triggered as well.

- Situation 4:

Other elements push the #x element out of sight or the #x element is pushed just enough where only a portion of the #x element can be seen in the web page.

**Heads up**

So how can I do this? I made many attempts to try to figure this out on my own but no luck yet so please provide a code example with my code in pure JavaScript only and please no jQuery examples or links to articles or other posts. I asked similar questions like this before in the past and no luck still. I just been

frustrated on the responses that I had been getting and now I question if this is even possible to do. I’m not asking any of you guys to do the code for me, all I’m asking if any of you guys can provide a code example with my code on how this can be done because I learned best that way just a heads up.

**My current code now**

```js
/*
????
if(???){
   var status='You can see #x completely in the web page.';
}

else{
  var status='You can not see #x completely in the web page.';
}

document.querySelector('#status-output').innerHTML= status;

*/
```

```css
html{
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

#x{
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px; /*<-- This should trigger the else condition because this makes the element not completely in view on the web page.*/
  left: 15px;
  background-color: lime;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#status-output{
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id='x'></div>

<p id='status-output'></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made this exmaple base on your code. The `checkSeen` function is what you need for checking if element can be seen base on its position. I have also add an interval to move the `<div>` around so that you can see the status update base on the `<div>` position. Hope this help.

```js
function checkSeen(id){
 var x = document.getElementById(id);
 
 if(x.offsetTop < 0 ) return false;
 if(x.offsetLeft < 0 ) return false;
 if(x.offsetTop + x.offsetHeight > window.innerHeight) return false;
 if(x.offsetLeft + x.offsetWidth > window.innerWidth) return false;
 
 return true;
}

function updateStatus(seen){
 if(seen){
    var status='You can see #x completely in the web page.';
 }else{
   var status='You can not see #x completely in the web page.';
 }
 document.querySelector('#status-output').innerHTML= status;
}


updateStatus(checkSeen("x"));

var testMovingInterval = setInterval(function(){
 var x = document.getElementById("x");
 if(x.offsetTop - window.innerHeight > 100){
  x.style.top = "-100px";
 }else{
  x.style.top = (x.offsetTop + 1) + "px";
 }
 
 
 
 
 updateStatus(checkSeen("x"));
 
 
 
}, 10);
```

```css
html{
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

#x{
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px; /*<-- This should trigger the else condition because this makes the element not completely in view on the web page.*/
  left: 15px;
  background-color: lime;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#status-output{
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id='x'></div>

<p id='status-output'></p>
```

Comment: OMG thank you very much this is what I was looking for thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```js
const winTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
const winLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
const winWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
const winHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
const xElem = document.getElementById('x').getBoundingClientRect();

const doesFit = xElem.top >= winTop &&
  xElem.left >= winLeft &&
  xElem.top + xElem.height <= winHeight &&
  xElem.left + xElem.width <= winWidth;

const status = `You ${doesFit ? 'can' : 'can not'} see #x completely in the web page.`;
```